Surge Supression in Large ESC Power Supply
I have 3 VESC ESCs (2 Flipsky 75200 V2 Pros and one Caesium Cs40 (200V design voltage)). The 2 Flipskys are being run at 75V, each with their own battery, and the Caesium is running at 150V, connected to the two batteries in series. Please see the crude diagram for details.

Recently, while trying to brake a very fast spinning motor, this Caesium Cs40 fried and caught fire. It also seems that there was an arc formed within the housing upon investigating the damage. The cause (I think, pure speculation atm) was the controller switched from sending brake current commands to handbrake current commands too early (I suspect) and the motor 'skipping' over this position hold caused a voltage spike which fried a mosfet and the magic smoke was conductive enough to allow an arc to occur(again, just spitballing).
Upon investigation, this event however also caused the other 2 ESCs in the circuit to also be damaged, one specifically had one Phase mosfet shot, and the other Flipsky was behaving wierdly, but not exactly clear why.
This is of course quite a costly failure, and I was wondering if there is a good way to reduce the risk of this happening. For example, via a TVS diode and a power resistor in series across the individual battery  terminals? Is this the best way to go about this, or have I overseen a better solution? If this is the way to go, do I have to worry about the surge suppression current damaging the batteries at all?
I'm from a low-voltage background, so this power electronics stuff is a little bit out of my league!

Please provide much more information about the used hardware.

Was the root cause really an arc flash and then damage? Unless very high voltage, semiconductor blowing out magic smoke and discoloring the surroundings is more likely, especially for "run close to its limits".

The ESC caught fire and upon opening up there were molten bits of metal sprayed across the PCB. I will update the question with more detail regarding the failure.
